# "Waiting for build to finish" in android studio while accessing activity_main.xml file

Tags: android, android-studio

After clicking on activity_main.xml file from res->layout the screen is showing waiting for build to finish for hours. I looked for some answers and also tried to tick **offine work** in **gradle setting** but still it is **not working**. I just started the course and have no knowledge, please reply.

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding?  Just click on "Build" -> "Rebuild" and it will clean out the prior build and do a full, clean build.

Comment: Can you share the complete gradle stdout / stderr output?

Answer (score 0):

This happens mainly due to dependencies not getting resolved because of poor network connection or hardware capability. Enable offline mode in Gradle settings if there are no network based dependencies.
Rather, clean the project, connect to a good network and do Sync Project with Gradle Files. This will make Gradle import again and run build.